# Как быстро смаштабировать готовый css-код, если размеры указаны в px?

Tags: css, масштабирование

Есть готовый рисунок на CSS. Его нужно вставить в проект, но размеры слишком большие. Можно как-то быстро его cмасштабировать? Очень лень все размеры переписывать.

Comment: что значит _рисунок на css_?

Comment: @Grundy скорее всего какой-то векторный рисунок состоящий из кучи блоков и кучи стилей. Естественно, для его уменьшения потребуется перелопатить кучу значений.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, ну не, векторный же как раз проще простого - он на то и векторный.

Comment: Не помешает сам код, рисунок поглядеть. Хотя, решением может быть только на JS, брать значения определенных стилей и пропорционально их уменьшать.

Comment: @Grundy имеется ввиду не SVG объект. Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/sashatran/pen/BpoLeE?q=css+image&limit=all&type=type-pens) для понимания.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, ну так это и не векторный рисунок :)

Comment: @Grundy технически - да. Рисунок нарисован не по координатам и является растровым. Но, визуально выглядит скорее как векторный, поэтому я его так и назвал, для лучшего понимания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Родительскому блоку задайте css-свойство `transform: scale(.5)`, это уменьшит ваш "рисунок" вдвое.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 40px/80px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.scale {
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">transform: scale(1)</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper scale">
  <div class="child">transform: scale(.5)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.